# Limiting the memory window of an LSTM network

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using an LSTM to explore some properties of long range dependencies in some data. One of the things that I was hoping to do was to examine the effects of limiting the "memory" of the network to different lengths, and seeing how well it could subsequently approximate the data for each.

How would this be implemented? Would it just be a case of limiting the length of the input sequence, or would it involve manually changing the values of the forget gate?

Answer (score 1):

The hidden state of the RNN maintains the memory. To limit the memory, you can reset the hidden state after some number of time steps. This can be done manually. It could also be done by giving shorter sequences, if your software automatically resets the hidden state after hitting the end of the sequence (this won't work with a 'stateful' RNN).

Answer (score 0):

As that put in @user20160's answer, the memory is just the states of all the cells in the seq2seq model. I'd like to suggest a method to do it. 
You can manipulate that by setting the [memory_sequence_length](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/attention_wrapper.py#L155) if you are using Tensorflow.

You provide a list of length sizes(for each sequence in the batch) and each memory sequence in that batch will be masked to be of that length.